# Simple PHP Object-Oriented $this

Tags: php, oop, this

I'm trying to brush up on some object oriented basics. I wrote this simple script but am confused as to why it works the way it does.

```
class Foo
{
function run($text = null)
{
    $this->bar = strtolower($text);
    echo $this->bar;    
}
}

$foo = new Foo;
$foo->run('THIS IS SOME TEXT IN LOWER CASE');
```

The script outputs "this is some text in lower case" as expected.

But what i'm confused about is why I can do this without actually declaring the `$bar` variable. Why can I just use `$this->bar`? Maybe i'm not understanding how `$this` works properly, but I always thought you had to declare a variable prior to using it in the class. For example `public $bar;`

Thanks for any insights you may have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP will auto-declare object variables as public if you are accessing them without declaring them as class members before. This is no magic, just a "feature" ;)

However, a good design should not use this "feature" but declare any class members explicitly. Your class should look like this:

```
class Foo
{
    /**
     * some description
     *
     * @var <type>
     */
    protected $bar;

    ...    

    function run($text = null)
    {
       $this->bar = strtolower($text);
       echo $this->bar;    
    }
}
```

Comment: You asked about the reasons why you should declare a public variable if it will auto declared anyway. There are a few reasons why this makes sense. Once is the the clarity of code, the other that comes in mind are reflectional tasks.

Comment: Yes that makes sense, I deleted my prior comment because you basically answered it when you edited your answer and mentioned the "good design" aspect.

Comment: As a good advice, I would declare any class member as protected unless there is a proper reason for making it public

Comment: The concept of dynamic properties are called Overloading in PHP. `Overloading in PHP provides means to dynamically "create" properties and methods. These dynamic entities are processed via magic methods...`. And overloading makes sense in some cases, too.

Comment: @redreggae Your comment does not fully apply here, as overloading will happen for previously declared `protected` in the same way as for undeclared members

Comment: yes, but in the magic methods you can distinguish if the property exists or not and what to do with the value. So this "feature" makes sense in combination with the magic methods.

Comment: Can you give me an example for what this should being useful? (I'm just asking)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to put `protected`, or `private` in front of your variable outside of your class methods to declare a class variable as anything but `public`. In PHP assignment is declaration, if it's not already declared. Note, you can also do this:

```
$ary = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
foreach($ary as $v){
  $newArray[] = $v;
}
```

Notice, I never declared `$newArray = array();` before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare variables in a class (a.k.a. properties) like so:

```
class Foo {
    public $bar;
}
```

Note the `public` keyword. Here, we are declaring the property's *visibility*. There are three types of visibility: `public`, `private`, and `protected`.

- **public**: You can access the property anywhere
- **private**: You can only access the property in the class it's declared in
- **protected**: You can only access the property in the class it's declared in AND any sub-classes

This also applies to methods. I won't go into too much detail, but you can read more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php).

---

If you don't declare a property, but set one in a method like you did in your example, PHP will automatically declare it for you and assign the value you specified.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

Consider that the same way you declare a variable that did not exist before, out of an object, the same way will happen inside objects, cause they are **poorly typed**.